# Is there a way to count dynamic table rows in citrix/image env in UIPATH

Tags: vb.net, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I am doing automation to download all document by customer.
i am having trouble with counting total rows in table because it is image based env. you can see the following image

[image]

i have tried to find selectors, but there is no selector
Can any body tell me how can i do it
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using image recording then try the following:

**1.** First select Image Recording and from Screen Scraping choose the option Screen Scraping as follow:

[image]

**2.** Just click on the image that you want to scrape data. In the follow up pop-up window select Region to Scrape option and specify the region/image to scrape as follow:

[image]

**3.** Then for your new scraped data select the following options on the right side as follow:

[image]

**4** The output of your recording will be **Text** (unstructured data), so let us covert it to **Data Table** (structure data) so we can count the rows.

**5** In order to do that we use **Activity Generate Data Table**

**6** Lastly we use **Activity For Each Row** to count the rows and store them in a **row_Counter** variable.

**7** Workflow as follow:

[image]

Hope these information will be useful.

Comment: thanks @konstantinos. this is exactly what i was looking for.